# How can I get the current user id in wordpress by making an ajax request from the website's front end (built in react on the same domain)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, ajax, wordpress

I have a wordpress website where react is used for all the front end components. I need to somehow fetch the currently logged-in user's id using the wordpress REST API via an ajax request. The request to the REST API needs to be authenticated in order to get this information but not sure how without the user's credentials in the first place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch a list of all the users using the `Wordpress Rest api` and then filter the result of a particular user based on your criteria.

Ref:- [Fetch all users](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#list-users)

Alternatively, You can fetch current user using this endpoint from the rest API provided by wordpress.

Ref:- [Fetch current user](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#retrieve-a-user-2)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. Is there a way to do this but when the front end makes a request to wordpress but they are on two seperate domains? Again remembering that I don't have the user credentials uprfront so I cannot use that for authentication.

Comment: You mean your front end is on a different domain and wordpress is on a different domain right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: In that case, you can make fetch all user call using the req URL where your backend is deployed and filter user based on criteria.

Comment: I ended up solving this using a similar method to what you mentioned. I used to the wp_login event to capture the username, set a cookie for it, detect it with javascript on the front end and then make a request to the memberpress rest api and filter using this username.